# I get "DevTools was disconnected from the page" error when connecting Arduino to the computer and switching between tabs

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, serial-port, devtools

1-)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvR69.png) 2-)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHaKq.png) I do not encounter any problems when I run the application without connecting the Arduino, but when I connect it to my computer via USB and switch to a different tab while receiving data through the application, I receive this error and the application stops working and I encounter a white screen. How do I solve the problem?

I'm pretty new to electron. There were solutions on the site under this title "devtools was disconnected from the page" error, but since mine was a more specific situation, I thought there might be a different solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.